# CentOS VM unable to connect to Internet via Proxy

Tags: proxy, centos, http-proxy

(Cross-posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1516816/centos-vm-unable-to-connect-to-internet-via-proxy)).

I have a fresh install of CentOS 7 in a virtualbox Virtual Machine (itself hosted on Windows 10). In VirtualBox, the network configuration for this machine is:

> Access method: NAT Interface
>
> type: Para-virtual Network
>
> Promiscuity mode: refused
>
> Cable plugged in: True

I am behind a proxy so on my virtual machine I have added my proxy configuration to:

`/etc/environment`:

```sh
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export https_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export HTTP_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export HTTPS_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
```

`/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh`:

```sh
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export https_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export HTTP_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export HTTPS_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
```

`/etc/wgetrc`:

```sh
http_proxy = http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
https_proxy = http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
HTTP_proxy = http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
HTTPS_proxy = http://my.proxy.server.here:8080

...

use_proxy = on
```

and `.bashrc`:

```sh
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export https_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export HTTP_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
export HTTPS_proxy=http://my.proxy.server.here:8080
```

I have rebooted the VM a couple of times just to be sure, but when I try to ping, all my packets are lost:

```sh
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.19.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4008ms
```

The VM only displays this one `eth0` connection and claims to be connected to it:

```sh
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:E8:76:82  
          inet adr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::a00:27ff:fee8:7682/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          RX bytes:11928 (11.6 KiB)  TX bytes:8682 (8.4 KiB)
```

The host machine has a correctly working internet connection and I am sure I am using the right proxy address.

What else do I need to do for my VM to be able to connect to the internet?

Comment: This looks like it would be on-topic for Super User, so I am voting to close it as off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions here need to be about programming to be on-topic.

Comment: @halfer that's fair, but do you know how I can get responses on superuser? It seems pretty... dead